# sort and list JSON array by property in swift

Tags: json, swift

I have the following json array

```
[
  {
    "name" : "v1",
    "available" : 1
  },
  {
    "name" : "v2",
    "available" : 3
  },
  {
    "name" : "v3",
    "available" : 2
  },
  {
    "name" : "v4",
    "available" : 3
  },
  {
    "name" : "v5",
    "available" : 3
  },
  {
    "name" : "v6",
    "available" : 1
  },
  {
    "name" : "v7",
    "available" : 2
  }
]
```

the available show some numbers which means:
1 and 3 is ok
2 is not ok

How can I order that json array by available value, showing first the 1 and 3 values and the last the value with 2. The result list should looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "v1",
    "available" : 1
  },
  {
    "name" : "v6",
    "available" : 1
  },
  {
    "name" : "v2",
    "available" : 3
  },
  {
    "name" : "v4",
    "available" : 3
  },
  {
    "name" : "v5",
    "available" : 3
  },
  {
    "name" : "v3",
    "available" : 2
  },
  {
    "name" : "v7",
    "available" : 2
  }
]
```

How can I do that?

Note: I use swiftyJson

This is my code:

```
sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: json_array)

func sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: JSON){
  let odds = array.filter{ $0.1["available"].intValue % 2 != 0 }
  let evens = array.filter{ $0.1["available"].intValue % 2 == 0 }
  print(odds)
  print(evens)
}
```

How can I return that as JSON?

Comment: create custom element and sort this after append

Comment: can you write a piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array: [Int] = [1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1]
array.filter({ return $0 != 2 }) + array.filter({ return $0 == 2})
```

Basically the logic is same.

```
let data = """
[
{ "name" : "v1", "available" : 1 },
{ "name" : "v2", "available" : 3 },
{ "name" : "v3", "available" : 2 },
{ "name" : "v4", "available" : 3 },
{ "name" : "v5", "available" : 3 },
{ "name" : "v6", "available" : 1 },
{ "name" : "v7", "available" : 2 }]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let array = JSON(data).arrayValue
let result = array.filter({ return $0["available"].intValue != 2}) + array.filter({ return $0["available"].intValue == 2})
```

Comment: I need with json array my friend

Comment: Not much difference in the logic.

Comment: Your code works great if the values are in range `1...3` but it will fail if there are other values.

Comment: @vadian Seems like there are only 3 cases?

Comment: All @Ryan has to do to make this work for _all_ values is change those filter conditions into `return $0 % 2 == 0` for evens, and `return $0 % 2 == 1` for odds.

Comment: @vadian, you said "Your code works great if the values are in range 1...3 but it will fail if there are other values." We can't know what order the other values should be displayed. Your "sort by odd/even and numerically within odd/even" approach is clever and meets the stated requirements, but we can't assume that the order of additional "available" values would follow that same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to sort the array by two criteria.

Suggestion aka usual algorithm: First sort by odd/even, if both values are equal sort by the integer value.

```
let array = [["name" : "v1", "available" : 1],["name" : "v6", "available" : 1],["name" : "v2", "available" : 3],["name" : "v4", "available" : 3],["name" : "v5", "available" : 3],["name" : "v3", "available" : 2],["name" : "v7", "available" : 2]]

let sortedArray = array.sorted { (d1, d2) -> Bool in
    let avail1 = d1["available"] as! Int
    let avail2 = d2["available"] as! Int
    let compareOddity = avail1 % 2 == 0 && avail2 % 2 != 0
    if compareOddity { return !compareOddity }
    return avail1 < avail2
}

print(sortedArray)
```

Two avoid ugly boilerplate code drop SwiftyJSON and use `Decodable` to decode the JSON into structs.
The code will look much cleaner (and is more efficient)

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted { (d1, d2) -> Bool in
    let compareOddity = d1.available % 2 == 0 && d2.available % 2 != 0
    if compareOddity { return !compareOddity }
    return d1.available < d2.available
}
```

Comment: Clever approach. (Voted)